# Differentiation (Transformation)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is related to transforming $\infty$ to the origin using the transformation $x=\frac{1}{t}$. So, $dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}dt$, which implies that $\frac{d}{dx}=-t^2\frac{d}{dt}$. I cannot figure out how to get the second order derivative, which is $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}=t^4\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+2t^3\frac{d}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets understand the first derivative using explicit notation, which makes it easier. From the chain rule we get

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(t(x))=f'(t(x))t'(x)$$ and as $t'(x)=-1/x^2$ this can be written either as

$$\frac{d}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d}{dt}\qquad\text{or}\qquad \frac{d}{dx}=-t^2\frac{d}{dt}$$

Now we can derive the second derivative following the same scheme

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(t(x))=\frac{d}{dx}f'(t(x))t'(x)$$ where we already used the known result from our first equation. Now we can again apply the chain rule and get
$$=f''(t(x))t'(x)^2+f'(t(x))t''(x)$$ and again reexpressing $t'(x)=-1/x^2$ and $t''(x)=2/x^3$ we get 
$$=f''(t(x))\frac{1}{x^4}+f'(t(x))\frac{2}{x^3}.$$

To go back to abstract notation, just ignore the functional arguments and you have your result

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}=\frac{1}{x^4}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+\frac{2}{x^3}\frac{d}{dt}\qquad\text{or}\qquad \frac{d^2}{dx^2}=t^4\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+2t^3\frac{d}{dt}.$$